# PowerShell - Cannot call web service method passing and returning object

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, powershell, object

I'm trying to call a web service method from my PowerShell script but it's failing. Here is the C# code:

```
public MyTable InsertRow(MyTable data)
{
   var dataContext = new MyEntities();

   dataContext.MyTables.AddObject(data);
   dataContext.SaveChanges();

   return data;
}
```

This is how I call it in PowerShell:

```
$uri = "http://localhost/MyWcfService/MyService.svc?wsdl"
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential

$t = $svc.GetType().Namespace
$attributes = New-Object($t + ".MyTable")
$attributes.Name = "Project X"
$attributes.Comment = "This is a test"

$resp = $svc.InsertRow($attributes)
$resp
```

And this is the error that I get:

> Cannot find an overload for "InsertRow" and the argument count: "1". At line:1 char:1
>   + $resp = $svc.InsertRow($attributes)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
This is the built-in .NET type when I call $attributes.GetType():

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     MyTable                            Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1WcfService_MyService_s...
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with how MyTable is defined/passed to InsertRow in Powershell. What do you get if you do `$attributes.gettype()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to call my RESTful Web service in PowerShell. I used this tutorial to [create entity data in a data service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756368(v=vs.100).aspx) and then used this [sample code](http://codewala.net/2014/01/06/how-to-consume-wcf-rest-services-using-c/) to consume the service using C#. This I have not yet tried, but I should be able to [use the C# code in PowerShell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx) (this being my project's requirement).